# How can I copy frames from one action to another action?

Tags: animation

I have 3D model with an "Idle" action with a gun animation action. I click on the + button new action in the Action Editor and then rename it to "Walk" action. I create keyframes, but when I check the "Idle" action the keyframes are gone or deleted.

How can I make copy frames with security from one action to another action for not need make all work for new actions?

Answer (score 4):

To solve this, you just have to put the armature(bones) to POSE MODE before copying the keyframes. Then copy (CTRL+C) the keyframes and paste (CTRL+V) to other action or a new action (+ button).

Answer (score 0):

Each time you change the pose of your armature you must press <kbd>I</kbd> with the relevant bones selected. From the drop down menu choose what should be saved...

[image: LocRot]

Make sure your cursor is in the 3D window when you click <kbd>I</kbd>.

Once a key frame is recorded a yellow diamond will appear in your Action/ Dope sheet. You can now move on to the next action <kbd>+</kbd> and change things - for example delete the keyframe from this action. If you go back to your original action you will see it is till there...

After comment: Make sure you haven't deselected the selected button

[image]

If you have the previous Action active when you hit the <kbd>+</kbd> it copies the key frames over to the new action.

[image]

If you click <kbd>+ New</kbd> without any Action active, it gives you a clean start.

[image]

Comment: yes is work but my problem is when i creating new action loose all poses another old actions and keed keys but poses gone :/

Comment: See pic added: Make sure you haven't deselected the selected button...

Answer (score 0):

I've followed your description here: I made an "Idle" action, hit the "+" button, deleted the keyframes, made a new action and called it "walk". I play "walk", then get "Idle" from the actions library and it plays. The gif is sped up but you should be able to follow and hopefully not lose any of your actions. If anything it's really hard to lose actions from the editor so I'm guessing your ones are actually still in there. Good luck.

[image]